# Logrotate doesn't work from cron on CentOS

Tags: centos, cron, logrotate

I have lograotate configured on CentOS 6. It works fine when I run it manually, but with CRON it doesn't work. Cron says in its logs: "All fine, I run you command" but nothing happens. Details:

*cat /etc/logrotate.d/myproject*

```
/var/opt/myproject/log/error.log {
    size=200M
    rotate 25
    missingok
    notifempty
    copytruncate
    nocreate
    nocompress
    nodateext
}
```

*cat /etc/cron.d/1everymin*

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
* * * * * root /etc/cron.min/logrotate
```

*cat /etc/cron.min/logrotate*

```
#!/bin/sh

#/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf > /logrotate.log
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

Every minute I see in /var/log/cron

```
Jan 16 21:40:01 localhost CROND[31541]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.min/logrotate)
Jan 16 21:41:01 localhost CROND[31552]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.min/logrotate)
Jan 16 21:42:01 localhost CROND[31561]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.min/logrotate)
Jan 16 21:43:01 localhost CROND[31575]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.min/logrotate)
Jan 16 21:44:01 localhost CROND[31587]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.min/logrotate)
```

But log actually is not rotated: nothing happens, /logrotate.log is empty

If I execute **/etc/cron.min/logrotate** manually all working fine, /logrotate.log have information about log rotating

Comment: Has the /var/opt/myproject/log/error.log gotten to the required size of 200M?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's manually filled up to 500 mb. Ok, I dont know why, but when I add the same cronjob via `crontab -e` under the root user it works fine

Comment: What are you expecting?  because it's really common for people to assume the logs will rotate every time logrotate is run.  That's not what it'll do here.

Answer (score 1):

If SELinux is enabled, cron will not be allowed to write into /  To see if it is enabled, use:

```
getenforce
```

Try logging somewhere else temporarily such as /var/log/logrotate.log

Be sure to look for denies in /var/log/audit/auditd.log assuming that auditd is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think `size=200M` is wrong, instead `size 200M` is correct as per log rotate [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) in your conf file `/etc/logrotate.d/myproject`